# How to get `std::basic_string<CustomClass>` to compile?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, std, stdstring

Ok, I'm usually all right at being able to read, understand and fix compiler errors. But with this one, I think I need help.

I want to have a `std::basic_string<CustomClass>` where `CustomClass` is a class. I don't want to write custom char_traits and allocator classes for it, unless absolutely necessary (i.e. I want to use `std::char_traits<CustomClass>` and `std::allocator<CustomClass>` if possible).

It compiles fine if I have no constructors in CustomClass. As soon as I add one, there are errors:

Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of `'std::__1::basic_string<CustomClass, std::__1::char_traits<CustomClass>, std::__1::allocator<CustomClass> >::__rep'`

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    //#include <vector>

    class CustomClass;

    typedef std::basic_string<CustomClass> InstanceString;
    typedef std::basic_string<int> IntString;

    class CustomClass
    {
    public:
        CustomClass()
            : m_X()
        {
        }

        CustomClass(const int x)
            : m_X(x)
        {
        }

    private:
        int     m_X;
    };

    int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
    {
        // This compiles fine
        IntString s1({1, 2, 5});

        // This would compile fine if there were no explicit constructors in Instance
        //InstanceString s2e = InstanceString({Instance(), Instance(), Instance()});

        // This generates errors
        InstanceString s2 = InstanceString({CustomClass(1), CustomClass(3), CustomClass(5)});

        std::cout << "Hello, World!\n";
        return 0;
    }
```

I understand this probably has to do with implicit/explicit constructors, copy/move semantics and stuff like that.

My question is:

- how do I get it to compile (i.e. what constructors/something should I add to the class)
- and how do I systematically figure out how to fix these types of compilation errors?

Comment: Wait.. why do you even *want* a custom class in a `basic_string`? Which features make you do that?!

Comment: No other STL containers guarantee a value initialized sentinel at the end? ;)

Comment: `Instance` has to be POD or standard layout (forget which).  I think the key component is the defualt constructor must be `=default`, as well as the copy constructor, and destructor.

Comment: I want `std::basic_string<CustomClass>` because I want to have strings of custom characters...

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov: That doesn't explain why the "custom characters" should be a *class*.

Comment: You're supposed to inherit from `std::char_traits`, not use a custom character type.  Although, gcc-4.7.1 compiles the above fine.

Comment: My sample CustomClass has just a single int atm, but the final version will have two fields, an int and a std::vector<int>. So that's why it has to be a class.

Comment: The standard uses *char-like types* to denote any non-array **POD** types, so I don't think this can be gotten to work guaranteedly.

Comment: @Dmitri: "My sample CustomClass has just a single int atm, but the final version will have two fields, an int and a std::vector<int>. So that's why it has to be a class." OK, that kinda missed what I was getting at. Why do you want to store these in a *string*, if you're just going to use them like a `vector`? `basic_string` is for ordered sequences containers of characters.

Comment: I can fall back to using a `std::vector<CustomClass>`, which is most likely what I'll have to do anyway. The reason I wanted to continue to use `std::basic_string` is for its functions like `substr()`, etc.

Comment: Using `substr` with a complex character type (if possible) would make an inefficient function even more so...

Comment: Just use `Boost.Range`, e.g. `my_vec | boost::adaptors::sliced(first, last)`.

Comment: Fair enough. I just wanted to get it to work first, worry about optimizing and performance later.

Thanks a lot guys, you've been very helpful! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the error message says

```
Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::__rep'
```

I'm pretty sure that `__rep` here is your `CustomClass`. It's saying it's trying to call the default constructor, but that's been implicitly deleted (by you providing your own constructor). I'm guessing that `basic_string` uses `std::is_default_constructible<>`. As such, you need to provide a default constructor using

```
CustomClass() = default;
```

as Mooing Duck suggested in the comments.

It seems likely that it actually uses `std::is_trivially_default_constructible<>`, which imposes the restriction that your class must be trivially constructible as well.

Comment: I think you're right.

I've replaced the `CustomClass() : m_X(x) {}` constructor with `CustomClass() = default;` and it compiled ok.

But now when I try to change it to have an int and a std::vector<int>, it breaks once again. I'll have to read more about what basic_string expects.

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov: It's not going to work with `std::vector<>` because a vector isn't trivially constructible. You should probably go accept Mankarse's answer instead of mine, because it explains why things are the way they are, unlike mine which just explains the requirements of your class.

Comment: Actually, __rep is defined as `struct __rep
    {
        union
        {
            __long  __l;
            __short __s;
            __raw   __r;
        };
    };` in file <string>.

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov: So it is. I think `__short` contains the `CustomClass` though.

Comment: I still need to figure out the difference between `CustomClass() = default;` and `CustomClass() : m_X() {}`, just to improve my error-understanding skills. But first I have to read up about what `constructor = default` means...

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov: It means use the implicit default constructor that you would get if you hadn't specified any constructor. And your explicit constructor is different than the default because you're initializing `m_X`, which the default constructor doesn't do.

Comment: Yeah, you're right about __short. __short contains value_type, which translates to std::traits_type<CustomClass>::char_type.

Comment: I've tried just `CustomClass() {}` and even that doesn't compile, unlike `CustomClass() = default` which does. So is it imposible to write an explicit default compiler that's identical to the implicit default one?

Comment: @DmitriShuralyov: I think the type trait is using a compiler feature to determine if the class has a default constructor. An explicitly-specified constructor is not default unless it's defined as `= default`.

Answer (score 4):

From right the very first sentence of the description of the strings library `[strings.general]/1`:

> This Clause describes components for manipulating sequences of any non-array POD type. In this Clause such types are called char-like types, and objects of char-like types are called char-like objects or simply characters.

`CustomClass` is not a `char-like` type because it is not a POD type, and as a result it cannot be stored in a `basic_string`.

The `libc++` implementation is failing to compile because it uses the short-string optimisation, and in doing so assumes that it is possible hold an array of `CharT` in a union without supplying a custom constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the concrete info. I had a feeling there'd be severe limitations on what's considered to be char-like types, but you've confirmed it.

Answer (score 2):

The short of it is, you can't use a custom `class`, because the short string optimization may use a `union`.

However, you can use an `enum` type.

It's quite a bit of work to do properly, and you do need to implement `std::char_traits` for your type.